# Export long HTML texts to email (avoid "The requested URL /... is too large to process" 414 error)

Tags: javascript, html, email, url, browser

I use the following mailto:... to export text to mail, but since sometimes the text is too long, I get the "The requested URL /... is too large to process." 414 Error. See: [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers) .

```
var URI='mailto:?subject=' + encodeURI(subject) + '&body=' + encodeURIComponent(body);
window.open(URI,'_blank');
```

How can it be done in a way that would allow to export an email longer than the URL limit length?

Thanks

Comment: Limit the input fields for Body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any other way to provide a purely in-browser interface for creating an e-mail, so you're pretty much stuck with the browser's URL length limits.

You *could* write some server-side code that lets you upload the text in question via an HTTP post request, and then sends the e-mail from the server. But, unlike `mailto`, that doesn't use the end-user's own e-mail program/address.